# shred multiple xml elements into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to shred this xml column into multiple xml columns but it seems to be in the wrong format.

Here is my data from using xml path()

```
<claim id="1111111">
  <InsHistDB>2</InsHistDB>
  <ClaimHistID>111111</ClaimHistID>
  <PatID>00000001</PatID>
  <ProcedureData>
    <row proc_logid="0000009" proc_logdb="1000000" createdate="2000-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2000-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0120" />
    <row proc_logid="1211557" proc_logdb="1000010" createdate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0220" />
    <row proc_logid="1211558" proc_logdb="1000010" createdate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0230" />
    <row proc_logid="1211556" proc_logdb="1000010" createdate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0272" />
  </ProcedureData>
</claim>
```

The select statement is currently this

```
SELECT TOP (1000)  [ClaimID] as '@id'
      ,[InsHistDB]
      ,[ClaimHistID]
      ,[PatID]
   -- ,[ProcedureData].value('declare namespace ns= "ProcedureData"; (/ns:ProcedureData/ns:row[1])','nvarchar(50)') as pp
     ,[ProcedureData]
     --,[ProcedureData].query('proc_logid').value('.','varchar(50)') as 'proc_1'
  FROM [Mine].[dbo].[claim]
  where claimid=1111111

 FOR XML PATH('claim')
```

What I am wanting to do is divide out the {Proc_Log_id} into different columns so the row should read.

```
Claim ID         INSHISTDB       CLaimHistID       PATID      Proc_Id1      Proc_ID2      ProcID3   procID4
 11111              2               1111111      000000001     0000009    1211557        1211558      1211556
```

Is this possible or am i just spinning my wheels? Also this will be for multiple patid's so the query without the where clause is expected. Also I believe there can be up to 10 proc_logids per xml data point. I am fine with null values, as i plan to pivot and normalize this data.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to select the 3rd node is `column.value('(/foo/bar)[3]','varchar(25)')`.

You are right to consider other options. The 'query' or 'nodes' functions in particular are better suited as they could return the values as a second result set or a new XML document.

Answer (score 0):

You can first graph the IDs from your XML content, and then you have to use PIVOT as you mentioned. Since you are not sure about number of columns, you can make use of dynamic pivot to make it more flexible.

First get the data using XML nodes and value and I stored the value in temp table as it would be convenient to do pivot.

```
Declare @xmlstring xml =  
'<claim id="1111111">
  <InsHistDB>2</InsHistDB>
  <ClaimHistID>111111</ClaimHistID>
  <PatID>00000001</PatID>
  <ProcedureData>
    <row proc_logid="0000009" proc_logdb="1000000" createdate="2000-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2000-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0120" />
    <row proc_logid="1211557" proc_logdb="1000010" createdate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0220" />
    <row proc_logid="1211558" proc_logdb="1000010" createdate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0230" />
    <row proc_logid="1211556" proc_logdb="1000010" createdate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" pldate="2015-09-21T00:00:00" adacode="D0272" />
  </ProcedureData>
</claim>' 

if object_id('tempdb..#temp1') is not null 
drop table #temp1

select m.Col.value('@id','varchar(150)') as ClaimID
,m.Col.value('(InsHistDB)[1]','varchar(150)') as InsHistDB 
,m.Col.value('(ClaimHistID)[1]','varchar(150)') as ClaimHistID 
,m.Col.value('(PatID)[1]','varchar(150)') as PatID
,t.new.value('(@proc_logid)[1]', 'Varchar(150)') IDcol, 
concat('Proc_ID', cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by m.Col.value('@id','varchar(150)') order by t.new.value('(@proc_logid)[1]', 'Varchar(150)')) as varchar(10))) AS ProcID 
into #temp1   
from @xmlstring.nodes('/claim') as m(col)
CROSS APPLY @xmlstring.nodes('claim/ProcedureData/row') as t(new);
```

You will have data in temp table like this. I have concatenated rownumber for a given claimID with proc ID to create column in the way you have mentioned.

```
ClaimID    InsHistDB    ClaimHistID PatID   IDcol   ProcID
1111111       2          111111    00000001 0000009 Proc_ID1
1111111       2          111111    00000001 1211557 Proc_ID2
1111111       2          111111    00000001 1211558 Proc_ID3
1111111       2          111111    00000001 1211556 Proc_ID4
```

Then you can make use of dynamic pivot to get your expected output.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.procID) 
        FROM #temp1 c
        FOR XML PATH(''))  
    ,1,1,'')


    set @query = 'SELECT ClaimID, InsHistDB,ClaimHistID, PatID,  '+@cols+'  from 
        (
            select ClaimID, InsHistDB,ClaimHistID, PatID, procID, IDcol  

                from #temp1
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(IDcol)
            for procID in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```

Final output from the query:

```
ClaimID InsHistDB   ClaimHistID PatID   Proc_ID1    Proc_ID2    Proc_ID3    Proc_ID4
1111111     2        111111    00000001 0000009     1211557     1211558     1211556
```